# Query embedded documents and list document with only matching embedded document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Please can someone guide me as to how I can accomplish the below. I have a Banks document, that is embedded with child document "branches" which in turn has embedded documents "branchcontacts" . I am trying to query for branchContacts with whose designation is Manager.

What I get is the complete Bank document with both the child branchcontacts. How can I ensure the branchContacts with ONLY "Manager" designation are returned as part of the Bank document.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("558e539941755bca3a966c10"), 
"bankCode" : "B001", 
"name" : "Progress Bank", 
"city" : "Paris", 
"branches" : [
    {
        "name" : "Standard-Gusto", 
        "address" : "address gusto", 
        "landLine1" : "343453453", 
        "mobile1" : "045865964", 
        "branchcontacts" : [
            {
                "contactName" : "Daniel", 
                "designation" : "Manager", 
                "emailID" : "daniel@prog.com", 
                "landLine1" : "3453453"
            }
            {
                "contactName" : "Lucy", 
                "designation" : "Accounant", 
                "emailID" : "lucy@prog.com", 
                "landLine1" : "7443456"
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "name" : "Standard-Pronto", 
        "address" : "address pronto", 
        "landLine1" : "763453453", 
        "mobile1" : "46585964", 
        "branchContacts" : [
            {
                "contactName" : "Mary", 
                "designation" : "Manager", 
                "emailID" : "mary@prog.com", 
                "landLine1" : "8453453"
            }
            {
                "contactName" : "Janet", 
                "designation" : "Accounant", 
                "emailID" : "janet@prog.com", 
                "landLine1" : "9943456"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$unwind" : "$branches"},
{"$unwind": "$branches.branchcontacts"},
{"$match" : {"$branches.branchcontacts.designation" : "Manager"} },
{"$group" : { "_id" : 
{ "fid" :"$_id" , "sid" : "$branches.name"} , "bankCode" : 
{"$first" : "$bankCode"} , 
 "name" : {"$first" : "$name"} , "city" : {"$first" : "$city"}, 
 "branch" : { "name" : {"$first" : "$branches.name"}, "address" : 
{"$first" : "$branches.address"}, "contacts" :  
{"$push" : "$branches.branchcontacts"} }
} },
{"$group" : {"_id" : "$_id.fid", "bankCode" : {"$first" : 
"$bankCode"} , 
"name" : {"$first" : "$name"} , "city" : {"$first" : "$city"}, 
"branches" : {"$push":"$branch"}
}}
 ]);
```